# Separator bar in numbered list breaks formatting

Tags: bug, firefox, list, commonmark

Using Firefox 110.0.

Including a horizontal separator (`---`) in a numbered list causes the item with the separator to overlap other items.

###### Markdown:

```
1. One
2. ---
3. Three
```

###### Result (image):

[image: Image of the result]

###### Result (rendered Markdown)

1. One
2. ---
3. Three

Comment: I'm not sure what a horizontal separator is doing in an ordered list; what do you want it to look like?

Comment: Well it *is* broken in a very broken way..

Comment: @JourneymanGeek It's not broken, it's an artefact of garbage input.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace Not an artifact of garbage input. The CommonMark specification [allows](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#thematic-breaks) for horizontal rules ("thematic breaks") to be part of list elements. That said, in the editor preview, it looks identical to the rendered post for me (I'm unable to reproduce).

Comment: FYI, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOIbG.png) is how it looks for me (Chrome/Windows) in this post as well as in the editor preview, which is obviously different from your "Result (image)". Are you saying this happens to you in both situations or only one of them? What browser are you using?

Comment: Update: I managed to repro on Firefox.

Comment: @Sonic_the_Anonymous_Hedge_Hog  Okay fair point.  But as a human person, I don't know what a thematic break is supposed to mean as a list item.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace I don't either, nor did I want to use it, it [just happened](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75497131/11683) in a question. If it's a valid markdown, it should be rendered properly. Even if it isn't, it should probably not generate something invalid.

Comment: @GSerg lol, "happened". That's one of the worst quality questions I've seen, it should be closed and deleted, OP clearly don't know how to ask. That said, can't see what you describe even there, so it's something on your side, or specific to your browser, which might not be supported by SE. (Sadly there's no list anymore, but they support only major browsers, not forks and open source alternatives.)

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars I'm using Firefox 110, and as [reported earlier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386826/separator-bar-in-numbered-list-breaks-formatting?noredirect=1#comment1289917_386826), it reproduces there. Irrespective to the quality of the original question, SO should render correct HTML in response to correct markdown (and preferably also not render incorrect HTML in response to incorrect markdown), just like a compiler should not crash on either correct or wrong code.

Comment: Looks like something they changed in the recent update break things then. SE should fix it, but you really should add your browser details to the bug report, it's trivial requirement. Any bug related to design/formatting might very well be browser specific so sharing this info is crucial. While editing you better also include [tag:firefox] tag as we already verified it's specific to the browser.

Comment: The "2." being displaced downward appears to be a bug in Firefox and should be reported to Mozilla. It doesn't appear to be a bug in SE's HTML or CSS. It's similar to the (now fixed) bug in Firefox which I [described in a comment on MSO](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418712/?noredirect=1#comment915178_418712) last year. However, I haven't looked at this one enough to see the exact combination of things which are triggering the issue. At a guess, the issue in Safari 14.1 (shown in the answer by Elements in Space) is a bug in Safari and should be reported to them.

Comment: @Makyen It seems to work fine on the CommonMark website (on Firefox) though. Here's an example: https://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/?text=1.%20Foo%0A2.%20---%0A3.%20Bar%0A

Comment: @41686 If that display is correct is debatable, but it's certainly better than the `::marker` shifting down, as it is here. I *did* test on the CommonMark site *prior to* posting any comments on this question or answer. The fact that it doesn't have the same issue in that page is one of the reasons I linked to my comment about the prior similar Firefox bug with the same element. As I was attempting to convey, this bug likely requires some combination of otherwise valid CSS, just like the prior bug. In other words, it's *expected* that the issue will not be displayed under all circumstances.

Comment: So, yes, SE could, probably, change the CSS for these elements in order to *work around* the issue in Firefox, and/or a bug could be filed with Mozilla to *actually fix the bug* that affects this one, *very* rare use case. Any way you cut it, the bug *still* should be reported to Mozilla, so that the underlying issue is *actually fixed*.

Answer (score 3):

Different web browsers render slightly different results:

#### Google Chrome (110.0)

- line appears between the first two items
  [image: example list rendered with Google Chrome - line appears between the first two items]

#### Firefox (110.0)

- line appears between the first two items
- second and third item lines collide
  [image: example list rendered with Firefox - line appears between the first two items, second and third item lines collide]

#### Opera (95.0)

- line appears between the first two items
  [image: example list rendered with Opera - line appears between the first two items]

#### Safari (14.1)

- line appears between the second and third items
- slightly larger space between item numbers and items
  [image: example list rendered with Safari -line appears between the second and third items, slightly larger space between item numbers and items]

---

### Is it a problem that different web browser render slightly different results?

Sure.

But *how much* of a problem is this really?
I can't understand why anyone would *want* a thematic line as a list item — it's syntactic nonsense.

Why should any effort be made to fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure what the intended output is but I can imagine it is either meant as a horizontal line within the list (i.e., indented) but without a number (so the 2 would not be shown and the 3 would be a 2), or outside of the list (i.e., not indented) but with continuous numbering before and after, or an abandoned attempt to put both a horizontal line and some content in a list item, like `2. --- Two` which would render as a line with the text `2. Two` below it. All three of those options are semantically valid in my opinion, although they may not conform to CommonMark or SE Mark.

Comment: The issue in Firefox is almost certainly a Firefox bug (similar to [this fixed one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418712/?noredirect=1#comment915178_418712)). The issue in Safari 14.1 appears to be a bug in Safari, but I haven't verified that. Both issues should be reported as bugs to the projects/companies responsible for the respective browsers. In other words, while SE might be able to find a *workaround* in each browser, these are *really* issues which should be resolved by the people responsible for the browsers, not SE.